# Is there plugin to integrate Crowd 2.8.4 and Nexus OSS 2.12.0-01

Tags: plugins, nexus, atlassian-crowd

Is there plugin which you can integrate Crowd 2.8.4 and Nexus OSS 2.12.0-01 . I thing that this is possible with Nexus Pro but is it possible with free Nexus OSS?

If anyone know I was very thankful.

Best Regards 
-Vesa Ala-Hakula

Answer (score 0):

See https://patrickroumanoff.github.io/nexus-crowd-plugin/ for:

> a fork from sonatype/nexus-crowd-plugin to support up to date versions of nexus and crowd

For versions:

> This plugin works with Nexus 3.x and Crowd 2.x